# Find $\mathbb E[|X|^2]$ for $X \sim N(0, \sigma I)$

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value

What is $\mathbb E[|X|^2]$, if $X \sim N(0, \sigma I)$ is a d-dimensional multivariate normal distribution? It is one of the steps in a question concerning Brownian motion and should be a very easy question, but I can't locate it using different online searches. For now I'm thinking it should be $d\sigma$ as $\mathbb{E}[XX^T] = \sigma I$, thus $$\mathbb E[|X|^2] = \mathbb E[tr(XX^T)] = tr(\mathbb E(XX^T)) = tr(\sigma I_d) = d\sigma.$$ But I am not sure if it's correct. Any remarks will be much appreciated.

Comment: It's fine. Quite simply, this is the expected sum of squares of the components of $X$.